# Android app link opens webview in Outlook instead of my app

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

My app is a hybrid with a native login activity and a webview. In some cases you get a link in an email that navigates you to a certain screen inside the webview. This part works just fine, the webview opens and the user is taken to the correct adress.

When the link is clicked in outlook the whole app seems to open inside outlook and I can even reach my native login screen still inside outlook. It's like my webview is hijacked.
Is there something missing from my webview config?

AndroidManifest.xml:
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidappshell"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name="package.name.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="package.name.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="domain.com"
                android:port="9201" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Webview setup:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private fun webViewSetUp(jsonData: String, url: String) {
    wb_webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

         override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            wb_webView.evaluateJavascript(
                "javascript:localStorage.setItem('clientMode', 'android')", null
            )
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            wb_webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:setUpAngular($jsonData)", null)
        }
    }
    wb_webView.clearCache(false)
    wb_webView.loadUrl(url)
    wb_webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    wb_webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    wb_webView.addJavascriptInterface(JsWebInterface(this, this), "androidApp")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my activities were not marked as singleton instances adding: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to my activites.